# Is there a tool to develop/design Watson Dialog XML

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-dialog

In sample dialog XML files I can see that some Id's like, getUserInput_2508591, output_2508575, search_2414738.

Are these ids generated from a tool ?

I am new to Watson Dialog XML , and just wondering whether there are any tutorials which cover best practices in creating dialog XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a UI editor for creating Dialog files, but requires an enterprise account.

Comment: Can you please share screenshot/url of the tool, I'm not able to find in the enterprise account.

Comment: You need to speak to your IBM representative, as they should be able to give you access. Going forward though I recommend to work with Conversation service instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool to create the XML files. But there are tutorials you can follow to create them more easily.

Link to tutorial: https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/dialog/tutorial_tutorials.shtml